# VS Code C/C++ Intellisense stop working after update

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-code, intellisense

After I migrate from TDM-GCC 9.2.0 to Winlibs (GCC 10.1.0 + LLVM/Clang/LLD/LLDB 10.0.0 + MinGW-w64 7.0.0 - release 2), Insellisense stop working. Any solution?

Here's my `settings.json`:

```
{
      "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
      "C_Cpp.default.cppStandard": "c++17",
      "files.trimFinalNewlines": true,
      "editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": "off",
      "editor.suggestSelection": "first",
      "vsintellicode.modify.editor.suggestSelection": "automaticallyOverrodeDefaultValue",
      "C_Cpp.default.includePath": [
        "c:\\mingw64\\bin\\..\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.1.0\\..\\..\\..\\..\\include\\c++\\10.1.0",
        "c:\\mingw64\\bin\\..\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.1.0\\..\\..\\..\\..\\include\\c++\\10.1.0\\x86_64-w64-mingw32",
        "c:\\mingw64\\bin\\..\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.1.0\\..\\..\\..\\..\\include\\c++\\10.1.0\\backward",
        "c:\\mingw64\\bin\\..\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.1.0\\include",
        "c:\\mingw64\\bin\\..\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.1.0\\..\\..\\..\\..\\include",
        "c:\\mingw64\\bin\\..\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.1.0\\include-fixed",
        "c:\\mingw64\\bin\\..\\lib\\gcc\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\10.1.0\\..\\..\\..\\..\\x86_64-w64-mingw32\\include"
      ],
      "C_Cpp.default.cStandard": "c18"
}
```

Comment: remove all the `..` directories and you see the true path that you add to the `includePath`

Comment: which compiler are you using: GCC or LLVM-Clang? What does Clang have to do with MinGW?

Comment: @rioV8 Winlibs (http://winlibs.com/) has a MinGW-w64 build with both GCC and Clang.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
"C_Cpp.default.compilerPath": "C:\\mingw64\\bin\\g++.exe"
```

to `settings.json`